# Chrome throws ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on localhost but not 127.0.0.1

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome

I'm trying to interface with a 3rd-party application. There's a piece of software installed locally, and a remote website I hit. When I go to the remote website, it makes a call to a web service at https://localhost:21113/ to initiate a process on the local software. This works in IE & Firefox, but not on Chrome. With Chrome, I get `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`.

If I change the address from localhost to `127.0.0.1`, it works (after I bypass the security certificate error). However, I can't change the remote website to use the 127 address, and we have a requirement to use Chrome.

I haven't been able to find anything useful in Chrome's issue tracker. I've tried clearing `DNS`, checked for proxying issues (not using a proxy), clearing the browser cache, resetting the computer, unchecking `Automatically detect settings` in the LAN settings (recommendation I found online), disabling all Chrome extensions, Incognito mode, and disabling windows firewall and my antivirus software.

None of these changes has had any affect. If I change the port it's trying to hit from 21113 to 21112, it instead throws `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, which is expected, since there isn't a listener on 21112.

When I go to chrome://net-internals, the number of events that appear for localhost is larger than the number of events for 127.0.0.1. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, this was due to Chrome [disabling NPAPI calls](https://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation). The 3rd party developer confirmed the issue and told me that this was broken due to the NPAPI deprecation and started working on a different method to fix Chrome support. I was also able to confirm by installing an older version of Chrome and found that the functionality worked just fine.